# Convert into array for PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a way to convert a string in the form show below into an array in PHP?

```
{1,2,3,4}
```

The string is stored on a database like this and I do not control the way things are inserted into the database.

Comment: Its not clear what you really want.what is your input and expected output.

Comment: He wants to convert that string into an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert it to a valid json array, then json_decode it?

```
$data = '{1,2,3,4}';
$d = json_decode(str_replace(['{','}'], ['[',']'], $data));
var_dump($d);
```

Comment: making an obviously non-json string json-like just to be able to use json_decode seems to me unsuitable. In my opinion an appropriate way would be to find out what format the source string is and see if there are some helper functions for that. If there is nothing to find, work with php string manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the leading and trailing curly braces, and then use explode to split the string by the commas:

```
$str = "{1,2,3,4}";
$csv = substr($str, 1, -1); /* remove braces */
$array = explode(",", $csv); /* split */
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) the brackets then [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

```
$string = '{1,2,3,4}'; 
$array = explode(',', trim($string, '{}'));    
var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just do:

```
$string = "{1,2,3,4,5}";
$array = explode(',', str_replace(array('{', '}'),'', $string));
print_r($array);
```

In function str_replace you just add every garbage character.